# FATAL EXCEPTION : Asyntask#5 Runtime Exception Android

Tags: android, httpresponse

This code sometimes works and Unfortunately stopped working. 
 I am not changing anything(UI) in background.

gives follwing error.

```
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-28 06:42:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4993):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

    And also could you please explain how to get Respose when i am recieving Respose as Event from TIBCO BE. it is replying with event with properties (Status).
```

IN onCreateBudle
     new MyTask().execute(u);
        startActivity(new Intent(AddUserActivity.this,InputActivity.class));

```
                ProgressDialog dialog;       
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddUserActivity.this, "",
                            "User is Registering...");

                }
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            String responseString = null;

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    HttpParams params;

                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);

                            responseString = response.getEntity().getContent().toString();

                            /*params = response.getParams();

                            responseString = (String) params.getParameter("Status");*/
                            out.close();

                        } else {
                            // Closes the connection.
                            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Handle problems..
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Handle problems..
                    }

                    return responseString;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    Log.e("OnPostExecute",result);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(AddUserActivity.this, "User Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}  }
```

Comment: Do you have more lines in the stack trace, like `caused by`? If so, could you add these lines to the post? Obviously, an exception is thrown inside of your's doInBackground but full stack trace for it follows trace that you already provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // super.onPostExecute(result);

       Log.e("OnPostExecute",result);
       try {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }


    }
```

try with this hop its helpful to you.