# AsyncTask HttpParams

Tags: android, http

Could anyone help me on following questions.

1) onPostExecute - Toast.make  while in background i am sending HttpRequest. 
    0nCraeteBunle - execute() ; startNewActivity
      showing error. AsycTask# Runtime Exception . 
     While commenting Http request in background, no error is showed.

here, how can i know that http Request and reply finished , so that i can start my new Activity.

2) how to get HttpParams. Sending from TIBCO BE (As event with properties)

3) What if i am recieving JSONObject, JAVAObject, Integer other than String in     onPostExecute. unable to override .

Comment: plz show some code what u have tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  protected class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "Loading", "Please wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //call ur HttpRequest
                   httpRequest();
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message Msg) {

        if (Flag) {
            //Add ur stuff
        }else{
                }
```

And then in ur method set `Flag` value

```
   public void httpRequest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String URL ="ADD UR URL";
    try {

        JSONObject ResponseObject = mAPIService.CallAPI(
                YourActivity.this, URL);
        String status = ResponseObject.getString("status");

            Flag = true;


    } catch (Exception err) {
        Flag = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Murali. But my code and my question ihave posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556813/fatal-exception-asyntask5-runtime-exception-android. My Task in background (AsyncTask) doesn't terminate and i start new Activity. That would be the problem.